# How to remove line limit from grep

Tags: bash, grep

I found that grep have some internal limit to number of lines processed.
Is there a way to remove this limit?

```
$ cat debug-2020-09-14.log | wc -l
5255625
$ cat debug-2020-09-14.log | grep -v "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" | wc -l
3239948
$ cat debug-2020-09-14.log | grep "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" | wc -l
0
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. For me, `yes a | head -n 5255625 | grep -v a | wc -l` prints `5255625`. What is your `grep --version`?

Comment: This is a customer server:
`$ grep --version`
`grep (GNU grep) 3.3`

Comment: @JamesBrown Ooops. What I used was `yes a | head -n 5255625 | grep a | wc -l` without the `-v`. I used `-v` for a cross-check. With `-v` the output `0` is expected of courses.

Comment: @HubertNNN Strange... I use the same version. Maybe aliases, functions, or environment variables cause this behavior? What output do you get from `yes a | head -n 5255625 | grep a | wc -l` and `type grep` and `declare -p GREP_OPTIONS`?

Comment: @Socowi I did your check and it works fine. Maybe its byte limit?
I am not sure what is causing it, I just found while debugging the application that logs end at 14:30 but if I dont do any grep, just tail, it ends at 23:58

Comment: @Socowi 
`$ type grep`
`grep is hashed (/usr/bin/grep)`
`$ declare -p GREP_OPTIONS`
`bash: declare: GREP_OPTIONS: not found`
`$ yes a | head -n 5255625 | grep a | wc -l`
`5255625`

Comment: If that helps here is the size of the log file (2Gb):
`$ ls -l debug-2020-09-14.log` 
`-rw-rw-rw- 1 debian debian 1978805982 Sep 14 23:59 debug-2020-09-14.log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you have binary data in your log file.
Once `grep` matches a line with binary data in it, `grep` prints `Binary file (standard input) matches` (to stdout, not stderr!) and exits. All matches after the binary part will be ignored.

To confirm this theory run

```
grep . debug-2020-09-14.log | grep -x 'Binary file .* matches'
```

If this is indeed the problem, then you can fix it using `grep`'s `-a` option. Here we also replaced `cat` and `wc -l` by `grep`'s capabilities.

```
grep -ac aaaa debug-2020-09-14.log
```

From `man grep`:

> `-a`, `--text`
> Process a binary file as if it were text;
> this is equivalent to the `--binary-files=text` option.
>
> `--binary-files=TYPE`
> If a file's data or metadata indicate  that  the  file  contains              binary  data,  assume  that  the file is of type `TYPE`.
> [...] grep  suppresses  output  after null  input  binary  data  is  discovered [...].  When some output is suppressed,  grep  follows  any  output  with a one-line message saying that a binary file matches.

Comment: Thats exactly what happend. Not sure why a log file contains binary data. Could you explain a bit more what the `-a` switch does?

Comment: Oh, and seems like the "Binary file (standard input) matches" message wont show in your example, but it will if you negate it like this: `cat debug-2020-09-14.log | grep -v aaaa | grep "Binary file (standard input) matches"`

Comment: Good catch regarding the missing `Binary file matches` without the `-v` flag. `grep` only prints that note when a *matching* line contains binary data. Therefore you know that the binary data is in a line without `aaaa`. I fixed the check and added a quote from `man grep` explaining what `-a` does.